# A simple python program not being able to access my dll

Tags: python, visual-c++, dll, scripting, mfc

I have created a simple MFC .dll file and I am able to access it via another MFC Application program. I was trying to do the same thing using Python 3.2.2 but after I load my library, It does not detect the function in my dll and gives an error like:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 358, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'SayHello' not found
```

..

I have trying to find a simple program to access my MFC dll file using Python but have got no success as of yet. Just to let everyone know, I have read on [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) and have been searching lots to get this working. My main aim is to use Python as a scripting language to interface with my MFC C++ dll. I have been reading lots and the closest one I could get to was with PythonWin. Please help in this regard.

Cheers.

Comment: Since you're using c++ you probably forgot to export the function as extern C (or maybe use some def file)? If you didn't c++ decorated the function name. Though I assume ctypes only allows calling C functions anyhow with some specific calling convention - seems problematic in C++ if you don't just use extern C.

Comment: I can't answer your specific question, but you might check out [Cython](http://cython.org) instead of using `ctypes` -- I suspect it would be *much* easier.

Comment: @ Voo: I did use extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)...but it still gives me the same error and I am still unable to access my function via Python. Just to let you know the dll I created, please check out this link: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/libraries/staticdll.htm

Comment: I am not sure why it is not detecting my .dll functions by default as soon as I load my library. I am 100% sure that my library is loaded, but haven't really been able to get through any of my functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get a hold of my problem and have solved it. For those who might expect this in the future, I would just like to paste the python script code in order to make your functions accessible in your python scripts. The way to go with your C++ function is obviously to declare this in your .dll file.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int SayHello(int strNo);
```

and your Python script should go something like this: (getattr() function is required to access your c++ function in your python script)

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("Location.dll")
hellofunc = getattr(mydll,'SayHello')
func2.restype = c_int
func2.argtypes = [c_int]
x = func2(34)
print(x)
```

...

If anyone thinks I might be wrong, please feel free to correct me. I am a beginner in Python, it worked for me this way and I am able to go ahead with my scripting after this.
Hope this helps others.

Cheers.